# Google cloud, BigQuery assets table, os_inventory.update_time

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have Inventory setup for GCP compute engines (VMs) and run export [commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/export) (daily) to create project level assets tables (for each project) in a BigQuery under `my-monitoring` project.

Then we can query VMs, let say installed packages. A query example, to see if the package "xxx" does exists for the VMs deployed at the `test-project`.

```
SELECT pack.value.installed_package.apt_package, os_inventory.update_time  FROM `my-monitoring.InventoryLogs.test-project_compute_googleapis_com_Instance`, 
unnest (os_inventory.items) as pack
where pack.value.installed_package.apt_package.package_name = 'xxx'
```

The problem is, it always shows as the package `xxx` does exist, if it was ever installed. If I remove the package later on, still this command shows existence. An output something like this:
[image]
As I understand, it shows an old logs. I looked at some other VMs, the value of `os_inventory.update_time` is very old. Does anyone know what this value is for and when it refreshes? I was expecting it gets updated every time we run export assets command. Any ideas how to query for the latest packages values at inventory table?

Or even any other solutions how to query for a particular package existence for all VMs across all projects?

Comment: What is the actual export command you run daily?

Comment: `gcloud asset export --content-type=os-inventory --project=test-project --bigquery-table=projects/my-monitoring/datasets/InventoryLogs/tables/test-project --output-bigquery-force --per-asset-type`

Comment: Your command seems to work fine for me. I tried creating a VM and installed `nano` just so it will create logs. Then I removed `nano` using command `sudo apt-get --purge remove nano`. I immediately ran the export command to check but logs did not update. I waited around 30 mins and re-ran the export command, and now the BQ logs are updated and I can no longer query `nano`.

Comment: Just a long shot, can you try running your export command with `--partition-key read-time` so it will partition the BQ data? This will introduce a new column `readTime` which contains the time when you ran the command.